# Why does Python's html.parser refer to unquoted attributes as "invalid HTML"

Tags: python, html

I've just noticed that Python's [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) says:

> Parsing invalid HTML (e.g. unquoted attributes) also works

An example would be the search form on this site which currently uses:

```html
<form id="search" role="search" action=/search class="s-topbar--searchbar js-searchbar " autocomplete="off">
```

note that the `action` is unquoted.

This is explicitly listed as part of the [HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) so labelling it as *invalid* seems incorrect.   The HTML syntax highlighter here even seems to do the right thing with it for me.

I'm aware that historically this was invalid, but continuing to label it as such seems gratuitous.  Maybe it would be more useful to document which parts (if any) of the current spec that explicitly aren't supported?  Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. The documentation is not perfect. You could submit a bug report: https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html